# Coupling from the Past: Why reuse randomness?

Tags: monte-carlo, simulation

In Perfect Simulation e.g., [Propp & Wilson 1996](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/206-RWG/RWGpapers/propp_wilson.pdf), we need to re-use the randomness.

I'm attempting to understand the Example on Page 6 of this paper, screenshotted below.

[image]

I see that this gives bias - but only because I ran a computer simulation using this scheme. I'm struggling to understand *why* we have this bias, and am lacking intuition.

Comment: The paper is too long to quickly read or understand what specifically you are asking about.  Are you asking why we might want to use a [random seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) in an experiment/publication?

Comment: No, I'm attempted to understand why for exact Monte Carlo sampling methods, also known as Perfect Simulation, if you do not use the exact same random bits, you have biased answers.